# What's a low overhead language for linux with MySQL support?

Tags: mysql, linux, shell

An Asterisk server needs to run an external script (an "AGI" if you must know) that queries a MySQL database. This script will run often, probably around 50-100 times per minute, and it doesn't do much (about 10-15 SELECTS, some calculations on the results and echos the result back to Asterisk).

If the script is a PHP shell script, during load testing it uses a lot of CPU (presumably as it loads the entire php library in and out every time it runs).

On the other hand if the script is a bash shell script, it takes a long time to run because bash can't (easily) maintain a single MySQL connection and doing 10-15 connections/disconnections to a remote server with SSL negotiation takes a few tenths of a second each so the script as a whole can take 3-4 seconds as a result.

What are some better choices of language for this task? Something with low overhead, but with easy MySQL support, preferably interpreted rather than compiled.

Comment: are the 60 to 100 per minute syncrhonous?

Comment: There will be times when one instance of the script will still be running while a second instance of the script has to start up, if that's what you're asking.

Comment: I mean does it block. In the end, try to share with the community what you came up with and the profiling of it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any language for which you start a new process 50-100 times per minute has some overhead. There's overhead simply to start a process, regardless of what language the program is written in.

Ideally, you'd avoid the overhead of the process by making a request to a service instead. But it sounds like you need to use the AGI interface, so you can't really escape this overhead.

All scripting languages (PHP/Ruby/Python/Perl) have interpreters that need to launch.

Even Java has a runtime JVM that needs to start up in each process, so this is an example of a compiled language that still has overhead.

A compiled language like C, C++ or Go is probably a good choice to minimize the overhead of the language runtime. All of these have programming interfaces to MySQL.